# How to convert a column into a list-column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a normal column to a list column in a `pandas` data frame? I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
df['popular_tags'] = df['popular_tags'].to_list()
```

The column currently looks like this:

```
df['popular_tags']

0 'A', 'B', 'C'
1 'A', 'B', 'C'
```

The expected output would be a list column, such as:

```
df['popular_tags']

 0 ['A', 'B', 'C']
 1 ['E', 'F', 'G']
```

Comment: What does you expected output look like?

Comment: Hi @mcsoini, I edited the post. I simply want the column in the dataframe to be a list column.

Comment: what does it currently look like?

Comment: `.map(list)` should work

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```py
df['popular_tags'] = df['popular_tags'].str.split(', ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      popular_tags
0  ['A', 'B', 'C']
1  ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Popular Tags': ["'A', 'B', 'C'", "'E', 'F', 'G'"]})

print(df)
    Popular Tags
0   'A', 'B', 'C'
1   'E', 'F', 'G'

df['Popular Tags']= df['Popular Tags'].astype('object')
df['Popular Tags'] = df['Popular Tags'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
print(df)

      Popular Tags
0  ['A', 'B', 'C']
1  ['E', 'F', 'G']
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was thinking of. Howver, I get an error that `'float' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Comment: @salix it's because there are some float values in the `popular_tags` column. You should either get rid of them, or try converting them to strings first: `df['popular_tags'].astype('str').str.split(', ')`.

Comment: @salix_august please check my answer - it's probably faster.